# DirectShow CLR having issue with global variables

Tags: c++, clr, directshow

I am trying to code up GMFBridge and DirectShow in CLR C++. I am trying to compare its performance against the GMFBridgeLib and the DirectShowLib in the same solution to see which is more efficient.

Right now I am following the GMFBridge source code for setting up C++ capture. One issue I am having is in objects that need to be global so that they can be accessed across the GUI buttons. The GMFBridge code does that as follows:

```
private:
IGMFBridgeControllerPtr m_pBridge;
```

that is then used in the setup code as follows:

```
HRESULT hr = m_pBridge.CreateInstance(__uuidof(GMFBridgeController));

if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return hr;
}

// init to video-only, in discard mode (ie when source graph
// is running but not connected, buffers are discarded at the bridge)
hr = m_pBridge->AddStream(true, eMuxInputs, true);
```

My current problem is that CLR states that any global has to be a pointer of some form, * or ^ depending on managed or unmanaged. It will not just let me add in a global variable such as the GMFBridge source code does. If I create a pointer:

```
IGMFBridgeControllerPtr* pBridge2;
```

and try to use that in my GUI code:

```
(*pBridge2).CreateInstance(__uuidof(GMFBridgeController));
(*pBridge2).AddStream(true, eMuxInputs, true);
```

It does compile, but when i run it, the code crashes with

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Program.exe.

Addidional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

on the block of code

```
void _Release() throw()
{
    if (m_pInterface != NULL) {            <--------------
        m_pInterface->Release();
    }
}
```

in comip.h line 823 called from:

```
HRESULT CreateInstance(const CLSID& rclsid, IUnknown* pOuter = NULL, DWORD dwClsContext = CLSCTX_ALL) throw()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    _Release();

    if (dwClsContext & (CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER)) {   <----------
        IUnknown* pIUnknown;
        hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pOuter, dwClsContext, __uuidof(IUnknown), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pIUnknown));

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = OleRun(pIUnknown);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = pIUnknown->QueryInterface(GetIID(), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pInterface));
            }

            pIUnknown->Release();
        }
    }
    else {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pOuter, dwClsContext, GetIID(), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&m_pInterface));
    }

    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // just in case refcount = 0 and dtor gets called
        m_pInterface = NULL;
    }

    return hr;
}
```

comip.h line 626 called from this line of code

```
(*pBridge2).CreateInstance(__uuidof(GMFBridgeController));
```

the only thing that seems to work is creating a local variable that is not a point object, but then i cant set it to a global, or use it across GUI objects.

if I make it local:

```
IGMFBridgeControllerPtr pBridge;
pBridge.CreateInstance(__uuidof(GMFBridgeController));
```

that works.

Comment: Making COM smart pointers global is a fundamentally bad idea, they'll call Release() after COM is uninitialized.  Your attempts at using uninitialized pointers just dig a deeper hole.  Stop trying so hard to make it global.

Comment: how can i control the directshow graph then? i have to create it on one button, start it with another and then stop it with another yet

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you do not assign anything to the pointer you declare:

```
IGMFBridgeControllerPtr* pBridge2;
```

You have to do something like:

```
pBridge2 = &m_pBridge;
```

Or just skip the use of `pBridge2` completely and use `&m_pBridge` instead.

Comment: i cant do that in CLR. the expression 
IGMFBridgeControllerPtr m_pBridge;
is illegal in CLR there must be a pointer indirection on it for it to be a global